# Why "long int" has same size as "int"? Does this modifier works at all?

Tags: c++, c, types, long-integer, abi

Ehm.. I kind' of though this modifiers like **long** / **short** expands / reduces amount of memory allocated when variable are created, but...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define test_int int
#define long_int long int
#define long_long_int long long int

void main()
{
    printf("%i\n", sizeof (test_int)); //output 4
    printf("%i\n", sizeof (long_int)); //output 4. Why? wasn't I modified it's size?
    printf("%i\n", sizeof (long_long_int)); //output 8
}
```

For unknown reasons, it prints the size of **int** and **long int** as same.
I use vc++ 2010 express edition.
Sorry, hard to find answer in google, it always shows **long** and **int** as separate types.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* the sizes be the same?! The types are different, that's all that matters. Each type can represent a set of values that's prescribed by the standard, but it's free to be able to represent more than that.

Comment: Whats **long** modifier does then? Aren't it supposed to expand amount of allocated memory?

Comment: Nothing of this has anything to do with "memory" or "allocation", and "long" isn't a "modifier". Rather, `int` and `long int` are two different types. Both represent integers.

Comment: As far as i know standard only says that long is at least as long as integer. It can't be shorter, but doesn't have to be more than int. Everything else is machine dependent.

Comment: The mandatory ranges of representable values are provided [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155838/596781). Noteworthy: `short` is at least 16 bits, `long int` at least 32, and `long long int` at least 64 bits. Everything else is unspecified. For example, a platform could very well have *every* type be 256 bits long, and thus `sizeof` every type would be 1.

Comment: I don't understand. http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/datatypes-and-modifiers-in-cpp.php here is written **long and short modify the maximum and minimum values that a data type will hold** are this wrong?

Comment: @Kosmos That site is completely wrong.

Comment: In fact, the entire site if very bad.  I found one or two serious errors on every page I opened.

Comment: Aww ok. I should find some other place to read then

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason that MS choose to make`long` 32 bits even on a 64-bit system is that the existing Windows API, for historical reasons use a mixture of `int` and `long` for similar things, and the expectation is that this is s 32-bit value (some of this goes back to times when Windows was a 16-bit system). So to make the conversion of old code to the new 64-bit architecture, they choose to keep `long` at 32 bits, so that applications mixing `int` and `long` in various places would still compile.

There is nothing in the C++ standard that dictates that a `long` should be bigger than `int` (it certainly isn't on most 32-bit systems). All the standard says is that the size of `short` <= `int` <= `long` - and that `short` is at least 16 bits, if memory serves [not necessarily expressed as "should be at least 16 bits", I think it mentions the range of values].

Comment: Indeed, it mentions that `short` should at least hold from -32767 to +32767. Note that the standard doesn't mandate -32768 (lowest value for a 16-bit number in *2's complement*) because specify how negative numbers should be handled.

Comment: Thanks alot Mats, but It seems long is used as an another alias for int for  the past 30 years! if it is not going to be greater than that, why bother mentioning it in the standard at all! It just makes no sense to have some thing called long, and not in a single time in 30 years, in major compilers and system, not providing more space than int!
This is ridiculous, All new languages have meaningful semantics, C++ is a exception in just every thing it seems!

Comment: @Hossein: 30 years ago, many compilers had `int` as a 16-bit value, and `long` was 32. These days, on non-Windows platforms that have 64-bit processors, `long` is indeed 64 bits, where `int` is 32 bits. But the main point is that there is no GUARANTEE that the type is any particular size for `long`, other than a minimum of 32 bits. It is then up to the compiler if it's larger than that or not.

Comment: @Hossein C and C++  are both used on many different systems, there are many non-windows systems, where a long is 64 bit. There are systems where an int is 16 bit, and a long is 32 bit.

Comment: Wow, 
huh, That hell is actual for windows only. At least, on macOS long is as expected 8 bytes.

Answer (score 13):

All that the standard requires is that:

```
sizeof(char) == 1
```

and

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

(and that the corresponding unsigned types have the same size as
the signed types).

In addition, there are minimum sizes for each type, indirectly
specified by limits on the values of `INT_MAX`, etc.: a `char`
must be at least 8 bits, a `short` and an `int` 16, a `long` 32
and a `long long` 64.

On 16 bit platforms, it is usual for both `short` and `int` to
be 16 bits; on 32 bit platforms (and the 36 and 48 bit platforms
that still exist), `int` and `long` are almost always the same
size.  On modern 64 bit platforms (with byte addressing), the
rational solution would be to make all four types have different
sizes (although one could argue that according to the standard,
`int` should be 64 bits, which would mean that `int`, `long` and `long
long` all had the same size).

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ implementations, a long is larger or equal to an int. Today's most popular desktop platforms, such as Windows and Linux, run primarily on 32 bit processors and most compilers for these platforms use a 32 bit int which has the same size and representation as a long.

Comment: That is incorret, `long` is "as large or larger than `int`". No requirement to be bigger.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `sizeof (int) <= sizeof(long)`. for 32 bit it is equal but on 64 bit it is different.

Comment: On 64-bit it MAY be different. It isn't on a Windows machine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In 64 bit compiler both int and log int are of 4 bytes.

If you are in windows go thorough the below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You may find some info in one other discussion:
[What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: In most 64 bit compilers, `int` is 4 bytes, and `long` 8.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ordering

```
char
short (int)
int
long (int)
long long (int)
```

The standard requires that `sizeof(char) == 1` is true.
The standard also requires that: `int` is at least 16 bits. `long int` is at least 32 bits and `long long int` is at least 64 bits.

With 32 bit processors being maintstream, compilers typically set `int` to be 4 bytes.
The extension hasn't happened again on 64 bit systems (for MSVC anyway) for the sake of compatibility.

Comment: urgh maybe that's why I though long int should me more than int. when I was learning c++, I started from borland c++ 3.1

Comment: C also requires that int be at least 16 bits and long be at least 32 bits.

Comment: I'm not sure you could say that `int` was ever "typically" 16 bits.  Back when 16 bit `int` was common, machines varied a lot more, and there were probably just as many which had 32 bit `int` (and at least a few which had 36 bit `int`, or other variants which would be considered exotic today).

Comment: And except for MSVC, 64 bit systems have an 8 byte `long`.

Comment: "except for MSVC" is a misnomer. For starters, IIRC the same applies to MinGW; then, I doubt Win64 is the only **LLP64** (`long long` and pointers 64-bit) platform.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you misconceive the meaning of int and long (that's not an adjective).

What the standard defines is that the numer of bits in each type requires this relation to stay in place:

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long).
```

`int`, by itself, can be as long as a `short` up to as long as a `long` depending on how the implementation is conceived.

Compiler designers tend to to maximize the performance of `int` arithmetic, making it the natural size for the underlying processor or OS, and setting up the other types accordingly.

But the use of `long int`, since `int` can be omitted, it's just the same as `long` by definition.

Comment: sizeof (long) == sizeof (long long) is possible, and common among 64-bit platforms besides Windows.