# Why are the long and long double type sizes different between Linux and Windows?

Tags: c, types, cpu-architecture, portability, abi

I am learning about computer architecture now.
Why the data type sizes are different between Linux and Windows operating systems??

This is my sample C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf ("\n-- General Data Type Size --\n");
    printf ("char size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(char));
    printf ("short size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(short));
    printf ("int size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    printf ("long size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(long));
    printf ("double size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(double));
    printf ("long double size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(long double));

    printf ("\n-- Pointer Data Type Size -- \n");
    printf ("char* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(char*));
    printf ("short* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(short*));
    printf ("int* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(int*));
    printf ("long* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(long*));
    printf ("double* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(double*));
    printf ("long double* size : %d byte\n", (int)sizeof(long double*));

    return 0;
}
```

when i compiled and run this code on my windwos 10 64bit with visual studio 10, it show like:

[image: windows result]

then, when i compiled and run this code on my ubuntu 18.04 64bit. it shows like:

[image: ubuntu result]

The Windows system shows me the size of long double is 8-byte and long is 4-byte.

But Ubuntu shows me the size of long double is 16-byte and long is 8-byte.
Why are the two sizes different? Both have 64-bit environments, and I wonder why they have different values. I'd appreciate it if you could explain.

Comment: An aside, did you know that you can simply use `"%zu"` as a format specifier for `size_t`?  (To avoid the cast to `int`)

Comment: Because they can. Why shouldn't they be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

Comment: Sizes are determined by the C implementation, not by the operating system or the hardware. General-purpose C implementations are largely influenced by the operating system and the hardware—key types, such as `int`, are normally chosen to be good for performance with the hardware and for interfacing with operating system features. But some types are flexible. E.g., one C implementation might choose to implement an extended-precision floating-point  type for `long double` while another might choose not to make that effort and leave `long double` the same as `double`…

Comment: … Or one C implementation might choose to use the old Intel 80-bit floating-point features for `long double` while another decides the performance of that is not worth it, especially if it interferes with modern features. And special-purpose C implementations, such as one designed to facilitate running old code for a particular environment, might largely ignore the operating system and hardware and make the sizes what they need to be to match the old code. You **can** write compiler software to make the types any sizes, so choosing sizes is a matter of satisfying your goals for the compiler.

Comment: Which compilers did you use?

Comment: @TonyTannous, that information is in the post - Windwos 10 64bit with visual studio 10
ubuntu 18.04 64bit, (GCC compiler is typical for Ubuntu 18, et.al)

Comment: Evidently the differences of the two environments you are using (Windows 10 64bit with visual studio 10 and ubuntu 18.04 64bit, with (assumed) GCC compiler) are a good illustration of the comments offered by @EricPostpischil on size of certain variable types, in particular the long floating point variations.  (I am sure Eric has a good reason why these very detailed comments were not placed in an answer, but I cannot guess what it is :))

Comment: @ryyker: I am just extemporizing. When I have time to think about it, I might move them to an answer. But I am away from home and administering things for my mother, so I am short on time. And this must have been answered elsewhere previously.

Comment: [Compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: For Unix systems, and those that followed its lead including Linux, [a lengthy whitepaper explores why LP64 was chosen instead of ILP64 or LLP64](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html).  I'm not aware of any similar resource for Windows, but [Raymond Chen offers some good reasons in a short blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563).  Basically, Windows made the decision to avoid 32-bit ⇒ 64-bit breakage by keeping `int` and `long` 32-bit, meaning only pointers would be changed to 64-bit; this is the LLP64 data model.

Comment: @pmg Wrong, `int` is at least 16 bit not 32 bit.

Comment: On my ARM Linux, `sizeof(int)==4`.

Comment: `int main() { .....` is not valid C code.

Comment: Short answer: Because Microsoft did never care about other standards and made their systems to be incompatible with everything else, including type sizes and calling conventions on AMD64/x86-64.

Comment: Partial duplicates: [Why "long int" has same size as "int"? Does this modifier works at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18353168).  / [What is long double on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15176290) / [Why are double and long double completely the same on my 64 bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922216) (many duplicates of why the MS ABI has double = long double with not a lot of design-decision focus on the answers.)  also related: [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429398)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: There was no "standard" to follow or disregard when Microsoft made that decision (not sure any official standard exists even now), just conventions. There was no strong reason why `long` *should* be a particular size, and porting 32 bit software to 64 bit land made it easier to stay 32 bit. Code that depends on `long` (or any integer type that's not from `stdint.h`) being a particular size was never portable to begin with.

Comment: Also related: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/ Bruce Dawson's excellent series of FP articles, including https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/ which talks about how MSVC configured the x87 FPU to round to `double` between operations anyway, not using its internal 80-bit (64-bit mantissa) precision.

Comment: @ShadowRanger x86-64 System V ABI