# Numpy returns different results on windows and unix

Tags: numpy

Given the following code:

```
import numpy as np
c = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

c = np.array(c)
print((c * c.transpose()).prod())
```

On my windows machine it returns **"-1462091776"** (Not sure how it got a negative from all those positives).
On ubuntu it returns **"131681894400"**

Anyone know what's going on here?

Edit: Apparently this is an overflow problem. (Thanks @rafaelc !)
But it is reproducible (Also thanks to @richardec for testing that)

So now the question becomes.. is this a bug I should report? Who do I report it to?

Comment: FWIW, on macOS (12.1) I get `131681894400`.

Comment: An overflow happened.

Comment: You can read more on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Sure enough, on Windows 10 I get `-1462091776`.

Comment: Looks like numpy on Windows is defaulting to int32 but on Ubuntu it's int64? Wouldn't go so far as to call that a bug. Perhaps it's discussed in numpy's docs?

Comment: On Windows, `c = np.array(c, dtype='int64')` will give the correct result. Not sure why the default dtype is different across different operating systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have enough comments that I think an "answer" is warranted.

### What happened?

> Not sure how it got a negative from all those positives

As @rafaelc points out, you ran into an integer overflow. You can read more details at the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) that was provided.

### What caused the overflow?

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine), numpy uses the operating system's C `long` type as the default `dtype` for integers. So when you write this line of code:

```py
c = np.array(c)
```

The `dtype` defaults to numpy's default integer data type, which is the operating system's C `long`. The size of a `long` in Microsoft's C implementation for Windows is 4 bytes (x8 bits/byte = 32 bits), so your `dtype` defaults to a 32-bit integer.

### Why did this calculation overflow?

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.iinfo(np.int32)
Out[2]: iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)
```

The largest number a 32-bit, signed integer data type can represent is `2147483647`. If you take a look at your product across just one axis:

```py
In [5]: c * c.T
Out[5]:
array([[ 1,  8, 21],
       [ 8, 25, 48],
       [21, 48, 81]])

In [6]: (c * c.T).prod(axis=0)
Out[6]: array([  168,  9600, 81648])

In [7]: 168 * 9600 * 81648
Out[7]: 131681894400
```

You can see that `131681894400 >> 2147483647` (in mathematics, the notation `>>` means "is much, much larger"). Since `131681894400` is much larger than the maximum integer the 32-bit `long` can represent, an overflow occurs.

### But it's fine in Linux

In Linux, a `long` is 8 bytes (x8 bits/byte = 64 bits). Why? Here's [an SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938192/why-are-the-long-and-long-double-type-sizes-different-between-linux-and-windows) that discusses this in the comments.

### "Is it a bug?"

No, although it's pretty annoying, I'll admit.

For what it's worth, it's usually a good idea to be explicit about your data types, so next time:

```py
c = np.array(c, dtype='int64')

# or
c = np.array(c, dtype=np.int64)
```

### Who do I report a bug to?

Again, this isn't a bug, but *if it were*, you'd open an issue on the [numpy github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) (where you can also peruse the source code). Somewhere in there is proof of how numpy uses the operating system's default C `long`, but I don't have it in me to go digging around to find it.