# cast of int,unsigned int for pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am new to pointers in C. Please help me with following code:

```
void main()
{
    int i=3;
    printf("unsighed Address of i = %u \n",(unsigned int)&i);
    printf("int Address of i = %d\n",(int)&i);
    printf("pointer Address of i = %p\n",&i);
    printf("Value of i = %d\n",i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
unsighed Address of i = 3219915640 
int Address of i = -1075051656
pointer Address of i = 0xbfec0378
Value of i = 3
```

As you can see, I am just checking address of `i` through `int`, `unsigned int`, and pointer. Unsigned and pointer values are same (0xbfec0378 of base16 = 3219915640 of base10). 
But integer value is different. int range is (-32768 to 32767). So I don't know how I got -1075051656. Can you explain this.

Comment: `int` is probably 32 bit therefore the range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

Comment: "*int range is (-32768 to 32767).*" Try this: `printf("min: %d max %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);`

Comment: For printing a pointer value you need to do this: `printf("pointer = %p\n", (void*)&somevariable);`.  The `%p` and the `(void*)` are mandatory, anything else is _undefined behaviour_ (google that term).

Comment: What makes you think _"int range is (-32768 to 32767)"_? What is your platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Range of values in C Int and Long 32 - 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6155784/694733)? It's not strictly about pointers, but the same issue.

Comment: That said, `printf("unsighed Address of i = %u \n",(unsigned int)&i);` is implementation defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cast a pointer value to an integer type, you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, which warrantee that the integer is big enough to hold any possible pointer value.

You may be compiling your code for a 32bit architecture, or you may be lucky enough so that your stack is located in the lower area of the address space (although this is unlikely), so that in your execution the most significant bits of the address are 0.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Code (https://ideone.com/2NDYnP):

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf
#include <stdint.h>   // intptr_t, uintptr_t
#include <inttypes.h> // PRIdPTR, PRIuPTR

int main() {
    int i=3;
    // Incorrect
    printf("unsighed value of &i = %u \n",(unsigned int)&i);
    printf("int value of &i = %d\n",(int)&i);

    // Correct
    printf("pointer Address of i = %p\n",&i);
    printf("uintptr_t value of &i = %"PRIuPTR"\n", (uintptr_t)&i);
    printf("intptr_t value of &i = %"PRIdPTR"\n", (intptr_t)&i);

    printf("Value of i = %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
unsighed value of &i = 3131233804 
int value of &i = -1163733492
pointer Address of i = 0x7fffbaa2d60c
uintptr_t value of &i = 140736324621836
intptr_t value of &i = 140736324621836
Value of i = 3
```

Comment: Note that correct specifier for printing `uintptr_t` is `PRIuPTR`, not `lu`.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you base `int range is (-32768 to 32767)`? That implies that the size is 2 bytes.
I don't think that is the case, since `-1075051656` is an `int` (you converted the address to `int`).

To check the size of an `int` use `sizeof(int)`, or to find the interval of values it represents, use `INT_MIN, INT_MAX` constants.

The size of `int` in your system is probably 4 bytes (32 bits), with interval `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. With `unsigned int` it is from `0 to 4,294,967,295`.

Therefore you can print the value using `unsigned int`, but it overflows when converting to `int` since  `4294967295 > 3219915640 > 2147483647`

Comment: Yeah what you said is correct. My system allocates 4 bytes for integer. Just checked it. So is -107505156 a garbage value? Usually when integer value exceeds bounds then it enters loop from negative end. Like int a = 2147483647. Then a+2 will be -2147483647 right?

Comment: Yes USUALLY. a+1 would be -2147483648, and a+2 would be -2147483647.

Comment: According to the standard integer overflow results in undefined behavior.